# variables scope in php

Tags: php, oop, phpunit

Why can I define a new instance of class `AdRequest` inside function like this:

```
require_once 'adRequest.php';
class adRequestTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{

  public $fixture;

  function testGetHash_returnsCorrectValue(){
    $fixture = new AdRequest();
    $fixture->site = "dummy.com";
  }
}
```

but when I am trying to create this instance like this:

```
require_once 'adRequest.php';

class adRequestTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{

  public $fixture;
  $fixture = new AdRequest();

  function testGetHash_returnsCorrectValue(){
    $fixture->site = "dummy.com";
  }
}
```

I got this error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$fixture' (T_VARIABLE),
>   expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create the instance once and use it in every function , use `setUp()`  , setUp() is called before each testXxx() method

```
<?php

require_once 'adRequest.php';
class adRequestTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{

 public $fixture;

 public function setUp() {

    $this->fixture = new AdRequest();
 }

 function testGetHash_returnsCorrectValue(){

    $this->fixture->site = "dummy.com";
 }
```

Comment: Is this a feature of some specific test framework? The normal PHP initialization method is `__construct()`.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you put between the declaration of a class and the methods, must be attributes of that particular class, not code.

In  your case, you should put:

```
require_once 'adRequest.php';

class adRequestTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{

  public $fixture = new AdRequest();

  function testGetHash_returnsCorrectValue(){
    $fixture->site = "dummy.com";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A class definition may only contain member declarations -- methods, instance variables, constants, and so forth. They may not contain arbitrary code in the same way a function body can.